# .addClass() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a tab switching function.

HTML:

```
        <span id="t1" class="location">Random</span>
        <span id="t2" class="location">Text</span>
        <span id="t3" class="location">TextText</span>
        <span id="t4" class="location">Asdf</span>
        <span id="t5" class="location">Fdsa</span>
        <span id="t6" class="location">Asdf</span>
        <span id="t7" class="location">Random</span>
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;
    color:blue;
}
.location {
    border-right:1px solid black;
    margin-left:8px;
    padding-right:8px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#t1").click(function(){switchTabs(1)});
    $("#t2").click(function(){switchTabs(2)});
    $("#t3").click(function(){switchTabs(3)});
    $("#t4").click(function(){switchTabs(4)});
    $("#t5").click(function(){switchTabs(5)});
    $("#t6").click(function(){switchTabs(6)});
    $("#t7").click(function(){switchTabs(7)});
});
var previousNumber;

function switchTabs(number) {
    $("#t" + number).toggleClass('selected');
    previousNumber = number;
    $("#t" + previousNumber).toggleClass('selected');
    }
```

When i click any of the spans it doesn't do anything. But if i do $("#t1").toggleClass('selected') it works. I have no idea what could i do wrong.

Comment: You are toggling the class and then toggling it back again! Overall, no effect. Switch your two toggle statements around so that you toggle the previous tab *before* you change the value in `previousNumber`

Comment: and you should really think about refactoring your code

Comment: This code could be greatly simplified.

Answer (score 5):

First, if they all have the same function, use the class to bind your click event.

You can use `$(this)` to get the clicked object within that function. You could also remove the 'selected' class from all before you add it to the clicked object.

Example:

```
$('.location').click(function() {
     $('.location').removeClass('selected')
     $(this).addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: You could probably cache `$('.location')` rather than forcing jQuery to reconstruct it each time.

Comment: The downside to caching `$('.location')`, or even binding to that initially, is that it makes the page less dynamic. If you were to add a new object with the `location` class it wouldn't behave the same way. You could do something like `$(document).on("click", ".location", function () { $(".location").not($(this).addClass("selected")).removeClass("selected"); });`

Comment: You could/should cache $(this) into a var, then use it to find siblings of itself which are .location.selected and then use it to add selected to itself. Requerying the entire DOM with the internal $('.location') could be costly if there the DOM gets large.

Answer (score 3):

```
function switchTabs(number) {
    $("#t" + previousNumber).toggleClass('selected');     // Do this BEFORE you update previousNumber!!!
    $("#t" + number).toggleClass('selected');
    previousNumber = number;
}
```

But, yeah, your code could really use some serious refactoring. You ought to be able to use a single `click` handler to handle all your tabs instead of attaching to each individual tab.

Something like:

```
var previousTab;

$('.location').click(function() {
     if (previousTab) {
         previousTab.toggleClass('selected');
     }
     previousTab = $(this);
     previousTab.toggleClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, i can't believe i made that simple mistake.

Comment: @123321123321: Wish I could say I've never made that mistake...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fiddle with a correct soution:

```
function switchTabs(number) {
    var t = $("#t" + number)
    if (t.hasClass('selected')){
        return;
    }

    t.siblings('.location.selected').removeClass('selected');
    t.addClass('selected');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YYq4U/1/

Answer (score 2):

I try this : http://jsfiddle.net/WV9ZQ/

```
function switchTabs(number) {
//$("#t" + number).toggleClass('selected');
if (previousNumber != null) {
    previousNumber.removeClass('selected');
}
previousNumber = $("#t" + number);
    $("#t" + number).addClass('selected');
}
```

maybe is what you looking for!